# How do I create a SaS token in Swift?

Tags: c#, swift, azure

Here's what I have so far. The commented out parts are C# code from Microsofts website that I have been trying to convert.

```
import CryptoKit
func GenerateSasToken(resourceUri: String, key: String, policyName: String = "", expiryInSeconds: Int = 3600) -> String?
{
    //        TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    let fromEpochStart = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    let expiry = Int(fromEpochStart) + expiryInSeconds
    
    //        string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
    guard let encodedResourceUri = resourceUri.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) else { return nil }
    let stringToSign = "\(encodedResourceUri)\n\(expiry)"
    
    //        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    guard let base64Key = key.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    let symmetricKey = SymmetricKey(data: base64Key)
    let hmac = HMAC<SHA256>.init(key: symmetricKey)
    
    //        var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
    
    //        var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);
    //        return sasToken;
  
    return ""
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token 
I'm slowly converting through the C# code and was just wondering if someone has this converted to swift already.

Comment: Do you want to generate sas on client side (iOS app )?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat Yes, I'm trying to do it from iOS app.

Comment: Hi @Paul if my answer help you please accept it :)

Comment: @VovaBilyachat Done. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to convert the code to Swift but, I was informed that this is a bad idea due to security reasons and it makes sense. I'll still provide the converted code here for anyone that needs it.

```
import UIKit
import CryptoKit

extension String {
  var hex: Data? {
    var value = self
    var data = Data()
    
    while value.count > 0 {
      let subIndex = value.index(value.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
      let c = String(value[..<subIndex])
      value = String(value[subIndex...])
      
      var char: UInt8
      if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        guard let int = Scanner(string: c).scanInt32(representation: .hexadecimal) else { return nil }
        char = UInt8(int)
      } else {
        var int: UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: c).scanHexInt32(&int)
        char = UInt8(int)
      }
      
      data.append(&char, count: 1)
    }
    
    return data
  }
}
func generateSasToken(resourceUri: String, key: String, policyName: String = "", expiryInSeconds: Int = 3600) -> String? {
    let fromEpochStart = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    let expiry = Int(fromEpochStart) + expiryInSeconds
    
    guard let encodedResourceUri = resourceUri.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) else { return nil }
    let stringToSign = "\(encodedResourceUri)\n\(expiry)"
    
    guard let stringToSignData = stringToSign.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    
    guard let keyData = Data(base64Encoded: key) else { return nil }
    let symmetricKey = SymmetricKey(data: keyData)
    let hmac = HMAC<SHA256>.authenticationCode(for: stringToSignData, using: symmetricKey)
    
    
    guard let hexString = hmac.description.split(separator: " ", maxSplits: .max, omittingEmptySubsequences: true).last?.description else { return nil }
    let hex = hexString.hex
    let unreserved = "-._~&"
    let allowed = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumeric()
    allowed.addCharacters(in: unreserved)
    guard let signature = hex?.base64EncodedString().addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed as CharacterSet) else { return nil }
    
    let SasUrl = "sr=\(encodedResourceUri)&sig=\(signature)&se=\(expiry)"
    let sasToken = "SharedAccessSignature " + SasUrl
    
    return sasToken
}
```

Comment: it is returning me 401 error, please help to generate correct token, you have already done this.

Answer (score 0):

Its bad idea to generate sas token on client side since you will need to compile with your storage keys then attacker decompile your app and get keys which will give them access to your storage/event hub and so on. That's is actually idea behind SAS token, so client app request short living and limited token to perform operation usually just a single one.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Would the better approach be creating the token on a server and make a get request to retrieve it? It is a hashed value after all with HMAC SHA256 so unhashing is not feasible.

Comment: @paul Yes exactly thats why we have sas tokens. Your app should call backend server to get that. This way you expose short living token which you can use to perform single operation. This way even if attacker gets your Sas they cant do much